# Read a Text File with Thousands Rows and Several Columns in VB6

Tags: vb6

I try to read my text file with thousands rows and several columns in it, but VB6 limit me with only 338 rows for the entire program. Can anyone give me solution for that problem?
This is the code I already try (that dat is a text file):

```
Public TF As Integer, SF As String, NoRs As Integer

Public Type tFile
 Number       As String
 Name         As String
 NIM          As String
 Class        As String
 Room         As String
 Department   As String
 Faculty      As String
 Univ         As String
 Role         As String
End Type

Public myFile(1 To 2650) As tFile '2650 is Number of Rows in my Text File

Public Sub cFile()
 TF = FreeFile
 SF = App.Path & IIf(Right$(App.Path, 1) = "\", "", "\") & "String\myfile.dat"

 Open SF For Input As #TF
 NoRs = 0

 Do Until EOF(TF)
  NoRs = NoRs + 1

  With myFile(NoRs)
   Input #TF, _
   .Number, _
   .Name, _
   .NIM, _
   .Class, _
   .Room, _
   .Department, _
   .Faculty, _
   .Univ, _
   .Role
  End With

 Loop
 Close #TF
End Sub
```

It work until Row 338, but if I scroll down pass that row, it will out of range.

Comment: "Scroll down?"  What are you trying to say?  What happens, some sort of unhandled exception?  If so telling us the error number and description might help.

Comment: Yes, I make it to show on a label and then it's able to scroll down. But, if I hit in rows number 338 I got run time error 9, subscript out of range.

Comment: Are you sure NoRs = 338? The only way I can see you getting a subscript out of range error is if you try to address a myFile index < or > the bounds of your array.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, that was at 338. That's why I wonder what's wrong with my code. Or is it a limitation by VB6 or something else